# Is there a better way to intercept the default Shopify customer login form and make it AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, liquid

So the default form is placed by Shopify using the following liquid:

```
   {%- form 'customer_login' -%}
```

I have created this hidden div for the Ajax response from /account/login:

```
  <div id="responseDiv" style="display: none"> </div>
```

Here’s the Ajax Script:

```
  var frm = $('#customer_login');

frm.submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          
              $('#responseDiv').html(data);
           if($.         ('#responseDiv .errors').length &gt; 0){
     console.log("ERRORS FOUND").    
       } else {
       location.reload();
      }},});});
```

With this script there’s a couple of issues when the form has errors, I’m quite new to JavaScript and would greatly appreciate it if anyone can provide/ helms me find a better way to achieve what I’m trying to do, thanks in advance.

Comment: By default, Shopify enable captcha code for frontend form and AJAX is not working that case.

Comment: Thanks for the response, captcha is disabled, the code above is working and the form is submitting.

Comment: *"With this script there’s a couple of issues"* - it'd be nice if you gave some more details on *which* issues there are. Don't make people guess.

Comment: Sorry about that, so the problem is when you submit the form without any fields filled and the response returns with .error included and then you re submit the form again without and fields filled it moves onto the location.reload, I’m guessing this is because the responseDiv is being filled with 2x the information?               Sorry if this is unclear.